# windows username: shortcut for current machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

Some applications insist that you write a username like `domain\user`, even if the current computer is not in a domain.

Is there a shortcut that resolves to `domain` to the `current` machine?

I mean something similar like these shortcuts:

- `.` for SQL Serve (`.\Northwind` resolves to the `Northwind` database on the current computer)
- `http://localhost/index.html` which resolves to `index.html` over `http` on the current machine.

Even better: is there a shortcut that points to the current user?

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is .\username

A . is local machine, so if my username is Ed then I would type .\Ed

Hope I helped

Comment: will try that and see if it works.